# Django: How can I delete specific records out of tables by using a view, a template and confirm in JavaScript in a django-template?

Tags: javascript, python, django, dom, django-templates

I have a model named Actie in models.py.

The context I passed: {'actie': Actie.objects.all(), 'user': request.user}

This is my template I rendered by a view:

```
{% for actie in actie %}
            {% if actie.actie_gebruiker.id == user.id %}
                <tr onclick="window.location.href={{ actie.id }}">
                    <td>{{ actie.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_naam }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_status.status_naam }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_aanmaakdatum|date:"d-m-y [ H:i ]" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_einddatum|date:"d-m-y" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_eindtijdstip|date:"[ H:i ]" }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actie.actie_gebruiker }}</td>
                </tr>
                <a id="verwijderenButton" href="" onclick="bevestigVerwijdering({{ actie_id }});"><img class="icontje"
                                                                                         src="{% static 'MyApp/verwijderen.png' %}"></a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<script>
    function bevestigVerwijdering(id) {
        var actie_id = '{{ actie.id }}';
        var antwoord = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze actie wilt verwijderen?");
        if (antwoord == true) {
            document.getElementById('verwijderenButton').href = 'verwijderen/' + id + '/';
            alert(id);
            alert(document.getElementById('verwijderenButton').href);
            //window.location.href= 'verwijderen/' + id + '/';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now what I want this code to do is that when I click on the image, that it deletes that specifc record out of the database.

It deletes nothing when I don't click on the first record but deletes the last record when I click on the first record.

This is my view:

```
def verwijderActie(request, id):
    Actie.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../../')
```

Comment: By putting the script in loop you are just replacing the function bevestigVerwijdering() again and again

Comment: the alert of actie_id returns me an empty alertbox when I put the script out of the loop.

Comment: put the function out off the loop and pass the id as an argument of onclick action... onclick="bevestigVerwijdering({{ actie.id }});"

Comment: you can use on ("click") and this to know which tr or a is selected

Comment: @TiagoGomes, I did what you said. Also I changed the function. The console.logs are giving me correct information but it doesn't delete the record. I can only delete the first record of the list.. (See the edited post)

Comment: Are you passing id as a string when it's supposed to be an int or vice versa?

Comment: @Tommy, No, I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a list of elements with the same id, then, when you call the javascript function, it gets the first element with the called id.

I would make something like that:

```
{% for actie in actie %}
    {% if actie.actie_gebruiker.id == user.id %}
        <tr onclick="window.location.href={{ actie.id }}">
            <td>{{ actie.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_naam }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_status.status_naam }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_aanmaakdatum|date:"d-m-y [ H:i ]" }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_einddatum|date:"d-m-y" }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_eindtijdstip|date:"[ H:i ]" }}</td>
            <td>{{ actie.actie_gebruiker }}</td>
        </tr>
        <a id="verwijderenButton_{{ actie.id }}" href="#" onclick="bevestigVerwijdering({{ actie.id }});return false;"><img class="icontje" src="{% static 'MyApp/verwijderen.png' %}"></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<script>
    function bevestigVerwijdering(id) {
        var actie_id = id;
        var antwoord = confirm("Weet u zeker dat u deze actie wilt verwijderen?");
        if (antwoord == true) {
            document.getElementById('verwijderenButton_'+id).href = 'verwijderen/' + id + '/';
            alert(id);
            alert(document.getElementById('verwijderenButton').href);
            //window.location.href= 'verwijderen/' + id + '/';
       }
    }
</script>
```